# Checking the background colour of the selected cell in a FlexGrid

Tags: if-statement, vb6, backcolor, msflexgrid

I need to do something in the `MyFlexGrid_DblClick()`, but only if the back color is NOT set to vbInactiveBorder, I tried the folowing code but had no succes

```
Private Sub MyFlexGrid_DblClick()  

    If Not MyFlexGrid.BackColor = vbInactiveBorder Then  
        _what I need to do_  
    End If

End Sub
```

During debuging the inside "*what I need to do*" works perfectly, but the check in `If` is always true, even when the backcolor of the cell I'm double clicking is previously set to `vbInactiveBorder`.

Comment: Have you tried checking the cell's background colour rather than the whole grid's? What are you doing to set the cell's background colour?

Comment: Are you sure that `.BackColor` is the cell's background colour? It's the [default background colour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228900(v=vs.60).aspx) here with [`.CellBackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239821(v=vs.60).aspx) being the cell's background colour. "BackColor affects the color of all non-fixed cells. To set the background color of individual cells, use the CellBackColor property."

Comment: Yes, it's .cellbackcolor now it works perfectly! thenak you very much @Deanna

Answer (score 2):

You're checking the wrong property.

[`.BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228900%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) refers to the default background colour of cells.
Try checking [`.CellBackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239821%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to get the current cell's background colour.

From MSDN:

> BackColor affects the color of all non-fixed cells. To set the background color of individual cells, use the CellBackColor property.